# JAVA adding jar file to project, module not found

Tags: java

I've added jar file to my project.
added it to the module setting as well.
and I getting this error :

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module jlfgr not found, required by UdemyFX
```

this is the sample.fxml :

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10">
<Button text="Click me!">
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/general/TipOfTheDay24.gif"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
</Button>
```

and this is the module-info :

```
module UdemyFX {

    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires jlfgr;

    opens sample;
}
```

I am using java 11, I have no idea why I keep getting that error.. ty!

Comment: Please also include the java command you used to run the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jar-File for module `jlfgr` is not in the module-path.

If you already have a module-path defined in your java call, then add the jar to this directory.

If you don't have the parameter `--module-path` or `-p` in your call, then add the path to the `jlfgr` module.

Example:

```
java --module-path . --module YourModule/path.to.your.MainClass
```